# Add Authentication to ASP.NET WebApi 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, restful-authentication

I have created a WebApi 2.2 project (from an Empty New ASP.NET Project) to prove some implementation concepts and I now want to add Authentication to it.

I notice that the only way to add Authentication on a new WebApi app is to use one of the (VS 2013, in my case) Templates.

Is there a sure-fire way of adding Authentication to an already existing WebApi 2.2 app?

I will only want to use bearer tokens, if that makes a difference to any answers I may receive.

Comment: There are several ways to add Authentication to an existing project. For example, you could use filters, possibly combined with attributes, either built-in ones or custom ones. You can also use a DelegatingHandler, although that is probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes you can add the bearer authentication from scratch, I'm not big fan of the VS 2013 templates because they mix between cookies and tokens authentication. You can check my [detailed blog post](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/) on how to add bearer tokens only to new or existing Web API project. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: That's a great post, but for the sake of posterity, could you add a quick summary to your answer? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259

Comment: Indeed - what if you aren't using Angular, just regular Javascript?