# Adding Authentication to ASP.NET MVC and WEB API project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have set up an ASP.NET MVC project with Individual Authentication. I added an ASP.NET WEB API upon setting it up. I now want to have a mobile application be authenticated by the project I've already set up. Even though i stand to be corrected, I'm aware that the Individual Authentication will support Cookie authentication but because of the mobile project i want to support Bearer authentication as well.

How do i add the bearer authentication to this project? Are other methods better than what i am asking here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Authentication to ASP.NET WebApi 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178888/add-authentication-to-asp-net-webapi-2-2)